# REST URL Design for Many to Many Relationship

Tags: rest, many-to-many, relation, api-design

So I got the models `User` & `Poll` where a user can create many polls (so we got a 1:n relation here) and the join table `Participant` as a user can be part of many polls and a poll can have many users.

**I need to define two REST endpoints**: 
One for getting a list of polls created by a user and one for getting a list of polls where a user is a participant.

For the first endpoint I defined:

```
GET /users/:id/polls
```

... which is the usual way of defining 1:n relations.

But for the second endpoint I'm completely clueless how this would look like in REST. I basically have the user and need all the polls where the user is a participant. I want to get things done and don't want to waste too much time so I came up with this abomination:

```
GET /users/:id/polls/participation
```

Has anyone a sane idea how this can be designed? Is it even possible to map this in a single call with REST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advocate making `polls` a top-level resource. You can then support

```
GET /polls?createdBy={userId}
GET /polls?participant={userId}
```

You can add other query parameters as needed. Another alternative is to have a separate resource, `poll-participants`, which holds the mapping.

```
GET /poll-participants?creator={userId}
GET /poll-participants?particpant={userId}
```

In this case, you'd get a resource which has a list of mapping objects. They could hold the whole user and poll in each one, or they could have links you have to follow to GET the full user and poll. This works best when the user and poll are cacheable.

Comment: So in example one you would use the parameter `participant` for `Poll` although it's only a virtual property? I see that `created_by` is legit as it's a real property on `Poll`.

Comment: @codepushr Yes. There's no rule anywhere that says only properties on a resource may be queried against.

Comment: @codepushr Sorry, I want to clarify something. The participants are properties of the *resource*. They are not properties of the *representation* that you're providing to your clients. And both your resource and representation(s) are totally separate conceptual entities from the data model convenient for your database storage, in the same way you don't restrict your UI design to map directly to your database design.

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as i got your question, you need to build simple get to aquire data.
I can suggest you add the get param like GET /users/:id/poll?participation=true. This can refer to your model and stay simple to understand.

Comment: Aren't query parameters in REST usually representing real attributes of a model? `Poll` has no real `participation` member, I just came up with that. The relation is modeled in the join table.

Comment: Never mind! Eric Stein suggested that virtual properties and queries are fine with resources.